# Is the formal power series ring integrally closed?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and $s$ and $t$ be variables.
Is the ring $k[s][[t]]$ integrally closed in $k[s,s^{-1}][[t]]$?

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  Every power series ring over a regular Noetherian ring is a regular Noetherian ring.  Every regular Noetherian ring is normal.

Comment: @JasonStarr But normal means integrally closed in its field of fractions, which isn't being asked.

Comment: @WillSawin.  I read the question in the title of the post.  I see that the OP asks a different question in his post than is in the title of his post.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I am sorry that the title was misleading.

Comment: @JasonStarr Fair enough!

Answer (score 17):

No. Let $\ell$ be a prime invertible in $k$ and consider

$$x= s (1+ t/s)^{1/\ell} = s  + \frac{t }{\ell} - \frac{(\ell-1) t^2}{ 2s \ell^2} +  \frac{ (\ell-1) (2\ell-1) t^3}{ 6 s^2 \ell^3} + \dots  \in  k[s,s^{-1}][[t]] $$

Clearly it does not lie in $k[s][[t]]$. But we have $$x^\ell = s^{\ell} (1+t/s) = s^\ell + s^{\ell-1} t$$ so it satisfies a monic polynomial equation over $k[s][[t]]$ (and even $k[s,t]$).